# Multer/Express not reading FormData sent from React Native client; From Postman reads & saves though

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, expo, multer

When I send an image to my node/express server that uses multer I am able to save an image to my "uploads" folder with this server side code and **request from Postman**:

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

app.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  console.log("file ==>", req.file);
  res.json(req.file);
});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("listening at http://localhost:5000"));
```

[image]

But when I try to send this from the RN client, it makes it past the middleware with no error, sends back the success message, but doesn't save the image and req.file is undefined.

Client side code and response:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, Image, View, Platform } from "react-native";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import axios from "axios";

export default function ImagePickerExample() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) setImage(result.uri);
  };

  const uploadImage = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("image", {
      uri: image,
      name: new Date() + "_profile",
      type: "image/png",
    });

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => console.log("result =>", res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && (
        <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
      )}

      {image && <Button title="Send to DB" onPress={uploadImage} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I can see that URI is saved to state `image`. I think my problem is with FormData and how I'm putting it together, but I can't spot the error when I look through docs / articles / tuts.

[image: Client side code and response]

Comment: The second argument of [`formData.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) must be a string or a Blob, but you pass an object `{uri: ..., name: ..., type: ...}`.

Comment: The same thing happens when I format like so: <br/>
`formData.append("uri", image);` 
`formData.append("name", new Date() + "_profile");`
`formData.append("type", "image/png");`

Comment: Is `image` a Blob? You `setImage(result.uri)`, which is a string.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen image (from state) is a string with the uri

I have also tried:`formData("image", image)` when I had the whole result as image object: `setImage(result)` => same problems

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have to use `var` or `let` instead of `const` when using FormData. Reason being, since you are appending data to the variable, it needs to be able to change the contents of the variable's memory.